# FlatList scroll doesn't work after wrapped by TouchableWithoutFeedback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to call `Keyboard.dismiss` on the root, but when I wrapped it like this, the `FlatList` is not responding to scrolling. Only scrolls when the keyboard is shown, how do I fix this?

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
            <FlatList
                style={styles.chatContainer}
                keyExtractor={history => `chat_${history.id}`}
                data={chatHistory}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.chatInnerContainer}
                inverted={true}
                renderItem={/* ... */}
            />
        </View>
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: color.white,
        height: '100%',
    },
    chatContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        overflow: 'visible'
    },
    chatInnerContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
        padding: 10,
        overflow: 'visible'
    }
});
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Result]

Comment: did you find a workaround?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue ?